# Validar, se já existe não faz INSERT

Tags: php

Eu tenho o seguinte código que regista no banco de dados o id de um artigo que o utilizador "gostou".

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO favoritos (id_user, id_oferta)
VALUES ('$login_session', '$id')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
echo "New record created successfully";
} else {
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
```

Da maneira que tenho o código o utilizador pode gostar do mesmo artigo as vezes que quiser.

Como poderei resolver esta situação?

Comment: Se sua tabela for MySql, crie um index único com os campos id_user e id_oferta ou então antes de fazer o insert, faça um select e verifique se retornou algum resultado, se sim, não faz o update.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

faz a busca desse favorito e caso exista não faz o insert.

```
$sql = "select * from favoritos where id_user=? and id_oferta=? limit 1"
$stmt=$conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->excute(array($login_session,$id));
$result= $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)

 if($result != false){ //ja existe
//   ..insere no banco
 }
```

Comment: acho que o meu cérebro estava a ser um pouco preguiçoso.. Obrigado John valeu pela ajuda. Um Abraço!

Comment: A maneira mais correta de tratar esse caso é com uma constraint. E se duas threads, exemplo, dois navegadores (dois navegadores criarão sessões diferentes, possivelmente threads diferentes acessarão o mesmo código) ao mesmo tempo tentarem adicionar como favorito? com esse código, poderia acontecer uma condição de corrida no IF e duplicar o favorito.

Comment: por isso que em tabelas NxN, deixa-se as duas chaves como primarias, evitando assim que aconteça alguma duplicata.

Answer (score 2):

Eu usaria `ON DUPLICATE KEY`. Pode ler mais na [*DOC*](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html). A vantagem é ter uma única query para *insert* e *update*.

```sql
INSERT INTO favoritos( id_user, id_oferta )
VALUES( $login_session, $id )
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE id_user = $login_session, id_oferta = $id
```

Answer (score 2):

Outra solução para não ter que fazer duas requisições no banco é fazer um *insert* com *select*:

```sql
INSERT INTO 
  favoritos (id_user, id_oferta)
SELECT
  ('$login_session', '$id')
WHERE 
  NOT EXISTS( SELECT 1 FROM favoritos WHERE id_user = '$login_session' AND id_oferta = '$id')
```

Answer (score 1):

Caso alguém tenha um problema semelhante, ficou assim o meu código:

```
//verifica se já existe
$query = mysql_query("select * from favoritos where id_user='$login_session' AND id_oferta='$id'", $connection);
$rows = mysql_num_rows($query);
if ($rows != false) {
echo "ja existe";
} else {

 //Faz o que eu quero :p
}
```